# Angular $ JS- Modal issue with javaScript file which include in the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I put the controllers in a js file under a directory called Scripts.
I the controller I open the modal dialog by clicking  on a button.
The htm of the modal is in a file under directory called Templates

```
 <button class="btnOpen" ng-click="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctrlTags', function($scope, $uibModal, $log){
   $scope.openModal = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '../Templates/myModl.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            param: function () {
                $log.log($scope.dt)
                return {'data':$scope.data,'date' : $scope.dt , 'input': $scope.myVar};
            }
        }
    });
};

}
```

In the html I added

```
<script src="Scripts/src.js"></script>
```

When I load the app in the app I got error when I click in the button which suppose to open the modal.

p.s
when the controllers are in a script tag in the html file the app works fine

Comment: is `Scripts/src.js` file loading correctly ?

Comment: do u see any console errors ?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/tpload?p0=%2FTemplates%2FmyModl.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:63342/angularjs/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:63342/angularjs/Scripts/angular.min.js:146:48

Comment: Have you included ui.bootstrap related JS and CSS files in your HTML ??

Comment: templateUrl: './Templates/myModl.html' . The path should resolve correctly.